# Update and select in a single query in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

At first, I want to update a table, then want to select updated rows. How can I do this in a **single query**. 
let say, I have updated a table following way

```
    UPDATE suppliers
SET city = (SELECT customers.city
            FROM customers
            WHERE customers.customer_name = suppliers.supplier_name)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT customers.city
              FROM customers
              WHERE customers.customer_name = suppliers.supplier_name)
```

Now, How can I select this updated rows

Comment: What's the host environment for the SQL? If PL/SQL then you can use `UPDATE ... RETURNING INTO ...`, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm Even if you are using eg JDBC or .Net you can send an anonymous PL/SQL block and retrieve the rows that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for oracle using Returning:

```
UPDATE <table> SET (c1) = (v1) WHERE <condition> RETURNING <expression> INTO <variables>
```

Comment: UPDATE MSFA.SAMPLE_STOCK SET MSFA.SAMPLE_STOCK.STOCK_REMAINING = '10' 
WHERE EMP_ID='1007355' RETURNING (select STOCK_REMAINING from MSFA.SAMPLE_STOCK) INTO var
it gives me the following error ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: Please tell us which programming environment you are using.